# What is the cause of this route-related error in my Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I am working on a Laravel application that requires user registration and login.

Alter registration, the users have the possibility to replace the default avatar image with *a picture of their choice*.

They should also be able to delete this picture and revert to the default avatar (default.png). For this purpose I did the following:

In `routes/web.php` I have the necessary routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/dashboard/profile', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');

Route::post('/dashboard/profile/update', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');

Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

In `Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController.php` I have:

```
// Delete avatar
public function deleteavatar($id) {
    $current_user = Auth::user();

    if ($id == $current_user->avatar) {
        $current_user->avatar = "default.png";
        $current_user->update();
    }
}
```

In the view I have this delete button:

```
<a href="#" class="icon text-light" id="delete-avatar" data-uid="{{$current_user->id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

The method is executed via AJAX:

```
(function() {
  //Delete Avatar
  $('#delete-avatar').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $avatar = $('#avatar-container').find('img');
    var $topAvatar = $('#top_avatar');
    var $trashIcon = $('#delete-avatar');
    var defaultAvatar = APP_URL + '/images/avatars/default.png';

    //Get user's ID
    var id = $(this).data('uid');

    if(confirm('Delete the avatar?')) {
      $.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/' + id,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(){
          $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $trashIcon.remove();
        }
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

#### The problem

For a reason I was unable to figure out, whenever I click the delete button, I get this error in the browser:

```
http://larablog.com/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/1 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're sending your ajax request via `GET` while the route is defined with method `POST` and is missing the `/{id}` segment.

Comment: @shaedrich I tryed `Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar')` and it does not work.

Comment: You forgot the slash after '`/deleteavatar`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have define your route as post method

```
Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

In ajax you passing as

```
     if(confirm('Delete the avatar?')) {
 var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
          $.ajax({
            url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/' + id,
            method: 'POST',
            data:{
    id:id,
_token: CSRF_TOKEN,
    }
            success: function(){
              $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
              $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
              $trashIcon.remove();
            }
          });
        }
```

**Updated**

As i see your code ,you are trying to delete loggedin user avatar .So

```
public function deleteavatar() {

        $current_user = Auth::user();

        $current_user->avatar = "default.png";
        $current_user->save();
    
}
```

Change route as

```
Route::get('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

In Ajax

```
(function() {
  //Delete Avatar
  $('#delete-avatar').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $avatar = $('#avatar-container').find('img');
    var $topAvatar = $('#top_avatar');
    var $trashIcon = $('#delete-avatar');
    var defaultAvatar = APP_URL + '/images/avatars/default.png';

    //Get user's ID
    var id = $(this).data('uid');

    if(confirm('Delete the avatar?')) {
      $.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(){
          $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $trashIcon.remove();
        }
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Here is the **[final version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67776214/4512005)**, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It either has to be:

1. GET (like ajax)

```php
Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

and

```js
$.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/' + id,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(){
          $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $trashIcon.remove();
        }
});
```

2. POST (like route)

```php
Route::get('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

and

```js
$.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/' + id,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(){
          $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $trashIcon.remove();
        }
});
```

3. DELETE (RESTful)

```php
Route::delete('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

and

```js
$.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/' + id,
        method: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(){
          $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
          $trashIcon.remove();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final version I got:

In `routes\web.php`:

```
Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
```

In the controller:

```
// Delete avatar
public function deleteavatar($id) {
    $current_user = Auth::user();
    $current_user->avatar = "default.png";
    $current_user->save();
}
```

In app.js:

```
(function() {
    //Delete Avatar
    $('#delete-avatar').on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $avatar = $('#avatar-container').find('img');
        var $topAvatar = $('#top_avatar');
        var $trashIcon = $(this);
        var defaultAvatar = APP_URL + '/images/avatars/default.png';

        //Get user's ID
        var id = $(this).data('uid');

        if (confirm('Delete the avatar?')) {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajax({
                url: APP_URL + '/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/' + id,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                },
                success: function() {
                    $avatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
                    $topAvatar.attr('src', defaultAvatar);
                    $trashIcon.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

It works.

many thanks to all that helped.